# Changing legend background color with css/javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to css/javascript! I apologize if this is a simple question. I am trying to add a legend to a map but I can't figure out how to make the legend background white. Right now, the legend is transparent.

Here is what I have in css

```
#legend {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
```

Then for js

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (mymap) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend'),
        grades = ["Library", "Parking Lot"],
        labels = ["http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/rangerstation.png", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/parkinglot.png"];

// loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
    (" <img src="+ labels[i] +" height='50' width='50'>") + grades[i] + '<br>';
}
return div; } legend.addTo(mymap);
```

Edit:
[This is what the map looks like right now with the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdjae.png)

Comment: Here is compelete tutorial for adding legend to map. I can not find your method in this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-legend

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood your posted code, but, you create a new element with `var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend')`, named **div**, right and you'd like to add background to it ? If so, try doing something like:

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (mymap) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend'),
        grades = ["Library", "Parking Lot"],
        labels = ["http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/rangerstation.png", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/parkinglot.png"];

        // Add the ID to the div element that will match #legend
        div.id = "legend";

// loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
    (" <img src="+ labels[i] +" height='50' width='50'>") + grades[i] + '<br>';
}
return div; } legend.addTo(mymap);
```

So, try adding the **`legend`** id  to the div element inside the function you have. If I misunderstood your question and this does not work, hit me up to change my answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering but when I added the div.id="legend", my Legend disappeared from my map

Comment: Do you already have an HTML element with an id of legend, because I thought that the `div` that you are creating, is the div you want to make a legend out of. If you have an element in the HTML, like `<div id="legend"> ... </div>` then the CSS you provided should be fine... but if you don't have an element with a `legend` id, you need to make it.

Comment: Yes, I do. I have this written in <body>
<div id="mainContainer">

<div id="mapid"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>
</div>